# Is there a google earth style map for Shadowrun 2050?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, maps

I started a campaign in Shadowrun 4e 2050 and would love to be able to send my players to a geography source without having them wade through the books.

It occurred to me that a custom Google Earth map would be ideal but I'm unable to find one from searching. I'd also be interested in ones from later time periods, but 2050 would be the best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a quite elaborate [SR3 Seattle Map](http://www.1w6.de/rpg/sr/map/) with city parts and safety zone demarkations.

Another, pretty [Seattle Map](http://www.chinagreenelvis.com/gaming/tools/shadowrun/map/), making different gang territories nicely visible.

There is a thread on shadowrun.com called [SR Interactive Maps vault](http://www.shadowrun.com/forums/discussion/26583/sr-interactive-maps-vault/p1) that collects some more.

Comment: Switched my accepted answer to this because it includes the thread where I was able to find even more maps that were relevant.

Comment: [This](http://www.1w6.de/rpg/sr/map/?borders=on) is the map that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 9):

[Downtown Seattle](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=212951523829166963716.0004ac4d9e1da20b35ece&dg=feature),
[Renton](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=212951523829166963716.0004ac750b4dc42581d18&dg=feature) and 
[Bellevue](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=212951523829166963716.0004ac4d7878baf34a983&dg=feature)

Bam.  There's three of them simply by typing in "shadowrun google map" into Google.

Comment: moral of the story, don't include "2050" in the search :)

Comment: That is probably because 2050 is somewhat atypical for SR4, AFAIR SR4 is set in 2070-2072.

Comment: Absolutely true. There was a 2050 sourcebook for SR4 which we're using, along with the actual SR1 missions, so I was hoping for maps. Interestingly I found exactly what I wanted on a german site after drilling down a few avenues.